# Wrapping/decorating a function in urls.py vs in views.py

Tags: django, decorator

So, I'm pretty familiar with wrapping functions in views.py. So I've written a decorator to redirect to the default REDIRECT_URL if the user *is* logged in (sort of a reverse `login_required`); it's based on how I've made views in the past:

```
def not_logged_in(redirect_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    def decorator(view_func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                redirect_url = (request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, redirect_url) or
                                settings.REDIRECT_URL)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

However, I get the following error: `'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'` which is caused by a MiddleWare expecting an HttpResponse. When I look at the value for `response`, I see that it's `<function wrapper at 0x2b3a9922a500>`.

Here's how I'm calling it in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'login/', 
     not_logged_in(auth_views.login), 
     {'authentication_form': LoginForm },
),
```

Comment: Your problem is that your decorator is not being used. You are instead returning the <decorator> function to `url()`'s second argument. Your decorator seems okay, but you should be using it like this: `not_logged_in(<your arguments>)(<view callable>)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here’s my implementation of the same thing.

```
def logout_required(view):
    def f(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return f
```

In `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^login/", logout_required(login), {"template_name": "users/login.html"}, "login"),
    # ...
```

I hope this helps (unsure though).

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to a decorator should be the function that needs to be decorated.

```
def not_logged_in(func, redirect_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
```

The decorator function is also not needed.  Return the wrapper function from not_logged_in.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've implemented your decorator, it is parameterised and therefore callable: that's why you've got the extra level of function that fizixx wrongly says is not required. You need to call the outer wrapper initially, in order to return the actual decorated function. So something like:

```
url(r'login/', 
 not_logged_in(auth_views.login)('/redirect/', 'redirect_field'), 
 {'authentication_form': LoginForm },
),
```

Comment: Hmmm... that's not working either. I guess the one thing I was never clear on with decorators was just how many nested functions are required, or why.