# Django: decorator causes 'function' object has no attribute 'get' when wrapping view in urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am using [Django defender](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender), [watch_login()](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender/blob/9a322c472920a71cb9d54d3d59e14a5ced75875c/defender/decorators.py#L6) decorator to add brute-force prevention to my custom login view:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.is_active:
            return redirect('home:home')   
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home:home')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Account is disabled')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Sorry, the username or password you entered is not correct')     
            return redirect('main:user_login')           
    return render(request, 'main/user_login.html')
```

However, when I wrap the function with the decorator in my `urls.py` file I get the error:
 `'function' object has no attribute 'get'`.

I have tried using the decorator in `views.py` with no arguments by simply doing `@watch_login()`. However, that does not seem to be working. How can I add this wrapper to my function in the `urls.py` file?

I have also tried this:[Wrapping/decorating a function in urls.py vs in views.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796897/wrapping-decorating-a-function-in-urls-py-vs-in-views-py/5797020#5797020)

And I still get the same error (`'function' object has no attribute 'get'`)

**EDIT**

I have also tried HttpResponseRedirect using the following method yet the user does not get blocked after reaching maximum login limits:

When user submit wrong credentials I do:

```
url = reverse('main:user_login')
return HttpResponseRedirect(url, status=302)
```

And as my decorator I have:

```
@watch_login(status_code=302)
```

Which still seems not to be working. And when I do `cleanup_django_defender` I can see there are no Attempts stored in my database.

**EDIT**

I had to render the template again on incorrect login rather than redirecting since it will be redirected with a new HttpStatus and `watch_login()` will never return true.

So now on a failed login attempt I simply have:

```
return render(request, 'main/user_login.html')
```

However, the issue with this approach is that the POST request parameters will not reset and as per Django documentation it is best practice to redirect after for submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `@watch_login()` [docstring](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender/blob/a1d526f3187d2d86152edec537b012bca3495794/defender/decorators.py#L6):

> To make it work on normal functions just pass the status code that
> should indicate a failure and/or a string that will be checked within
> the response body.

Which means your `user_login()` function should return a specific status code (and/or a message) on error.

[Example from tests 1](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender/blob/9a322c472920a71cb9d54d3d59e14a5ced75875c/defender/tests.py#L841-L844):

> ```
> @watch_login(status_code=401)
> def fake_api_401_login_view_without_msg(request):
>     """ Fake the api login with 401 """
>     return HttpResponse(status=401)
> ```

[Example from tests 2](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender/blob/9a322c472920a71cb9d54d3d59e14a5ced75875c/defender/tests.py#L872-L875):

> ```
> @watch_login(status_code=401, msg="Invalid credentials")
> def fake_api_401_login_view_without_msg(request):
>     """ Fake the api login with 401 """
>     return HttpResponse("Sorry, Invalid credentials", status=401)
> ```

**EDIT**

If you redirect on failed login [this condition](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender/blob/a1d526f3187d2d86152edec537b012bca3495794/defender/decorators.py#L29-L34) from `@watch_login()` will never evaluate to true (because `response.status_code == 302`).

> ```
> if status_code == 302:  # standard Django login view
>     login_unsuccessful = (
>         response
>         and not response.has_header("location")
>         and response.status_code != status_code
>     )
> ```

Comment: So to redirect to my main page after incorrect login, I should use `HttpResponseRedirect()`? Since I would like to redirect users to log in when they submit wrong credentials.

Comment: You use 302 on login success and failure which is why `@watch_login()` doesn't work. Just return a different status code on failure and use that status code in `@watch_login`.

Comment: I was able to fix it per your previous comment by simply rendering the page instead of redirecting so that worked.

Comment: Rendering can cause issues with POST parameters so according to your second comment, should I for instance return a `HttpResponseRedirect(myurl, status=303)`?

Comment: This is a rather odd situation. 302 makes sense, but at the same time you want to let the user know auth failed, i.e. 401. I am honestly not sure which status is better in this case, 303 should  be fine. Another way to keep 302 and make `watch_login` work is to set `location` header (as per the condition linked in my response). BTW it seems like there isn't one to rule them all answer to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839585/what-is-correct-http-status-code-when-redirecting-to-a-login-page.